# Android Send Text with custom emoticons

Tags: android, keyboard, emoticons

I have made a custom keyboard with my custom emoji icons. I have two devices and I have installed the keyboard on both of them. But when I try to send my icons to the other person through normal text, they show up as boxes and not the emoticons. What do I have to do to make my emoticons visible to the other person also? Android looks in the default folder (res/drawables). Is there anyway to make it look at my own folder when my keyboard is selected?

Answer (score 0):

The other person has to have your emoticons stored somewhere in his/her phone as well, otherwise you can't show them. That is, if the other person does not have your custom keyboard installed, he/she will not have your emoticons.

Another solution if he/she doesn't have them is to send the whole emoticon when used for first time (if whatever chat program you're using supports this, that is).

Comment: The problem is that android looks for emoticons in the default folder of its sdk, when using the default android application for sending messages. So I have no control over the EditText of that message box. How can I show my emoticon there?

Comment: You need to specify a different path for your emoticons, like on `/mnt/sdcard/`, not `res/`. You still need to send the emoticons to the other part before they can see them anyway.